# If $e^y=\sec x + k$, then why do we need to write $y = \ln |\sec x + k|$, with absolute value, instead of just $y = \ln(\sec x + k)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the following differential equation to solve:

$$e^{-y}\sin x - \frac{dy}{dx} \cos^{2}x = 0$$

I got the solution $y = \ln(\sec x + k)$. Now the solution given was $y = \ln |\sec x + k|$.

Why do we need the absolute value if in the preliminary step to the final solution $e^y=\sec x + k$ suggests that, since $e^y > 0$, then so too is $\sec x + k$, and hence there is no need for the absolute value?

Can someone kindly clarify what I am missing?

Comment: You are missing nothing, the absolute values extend the domain of the expression, but not of the solution. They do not follow organically from the solution.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so does that mean if I said something along the lines of "since e^y > 0 then y = ln (sec x + k)" and I could omit the absolute values?

Comment: Yes. Whenever $\sec x+k$ changes sign, the expression for the solution has a singularity, which is a domain boundary for the solution. As you start with $\sec x_0+k=e^{y_0}>0$, the sign is always positive on the domain of the solution, so the absolute value is superfluous. It is not wrong to put the absolute value, but it is also not wrong to leave it out.

Comment: @LutzLehmann awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that comes to mind is that your solution is not defined over all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, as $\sec(x)+k$ will become negative at some $x$ for any value of $k$. The solution given is however defined for all $x\in \mathbb{R}-\{\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi : k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, but when $\sec(x)+k$ becomes negative, this solution doesn't satisfy the given differential equation. [image]

In my opinion your solution is better as it satisfies the differential wherever it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you were given is wrong. If $x$ is near $\pi$ and $k$ <1 than the given "solution" is invalid.